# Does Ecto.Adapters.SQL.stream fires multiple query?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to write a cron which will write a large dataset to csv file periodically and upload to s3. So to not use offset/limit batching am using trying to use the stream feature and write the data to csv. Since the query is bit complicated am using raw query here, so couldn't use `Repo.stream` and stumbled upon `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.stream` which takes a raw query and a batch size. Couldn't figure out how the particular api works by looking at the docs, Would be very generous if someone can explain.

And am very new to elixir community, so any resource which have detaild explaination will help.

Comment: Btw this has nothing to do with phoenix-framework, so you may want to remove that tag.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#stream/4):

> Behaviour depends on the adapter.

The implementation details will depend on the underlying database that you're using. `Ecto.Adapters.SQL` is just the public interface, which you set up to use an "actual" DB adapter, such as `Postgrex` for Postgres, `MyXQL` for MySQL, etc.

> `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.stream` which takes a raw query and a batch size

That function does NOT take a batch size. The docs show an option for `:max_rows`, which is the maximum number of rows for the entire stream. **None of the docs (that I could find) say anything about batching.**

If you want to check for yourself, here are the docs for some of the specific DB providers:

- [`Postgrex.stream/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/postgrex/Postgrex.html#stream/4)
- [`MyXQL.stream/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/myxql/0.5.1/MyXQL.html#stream/4)

Comment: thanks for the explanation and reference, my bad it's not batch size.